# Prevent HTML 5 `video` from flashing poster image on src change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-video

In React, I'm using a `video` element to dynamically load static video files depending on what button the user clicks, and each time the video changes the poster image is displayed briefly. Here's what my video player markup looks like:

```
<video
    id="video-player"
    controls
    controlsList="nodownload"
    autoPlay={props.autoplay}
    src={props.video}
    onMouseOver={(e) => e.target.controls = true}
    onMouseOut={(e) => e.target.controls = false}
    poster={poster}
>
```

I'm trying to find a way to wait for the new video to load before stopping the old one so I can get rid of the quick flash of the poster image in between videos.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You could try using a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to load a new video element, and then replacing the video element when it resolves.

Comment: What would I load in the promise?  A video react/DOM element?  And how can I know it’s finished loading?

Comment: You could load a new video element, and the promise would only resolve once it has finished loading the element. Alternatively you could use the `onLoad` event to detect when the video has finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the components `setState()` method to achieve this. Your video source will look like `src=state.videoSrc` while your button handler will be something like this:

```
myButtonHandler(videoSrc) {
  this.setState({
    videoSrc
  })
}
```

`videoSrc` will be your static string which represents the url.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I got that part working fine!  My problem is that the poster image flashes when loading new videos, and I’d like the video player to just keep playing the old video until the new one is ready to go

Comment: you probably need two elements, one for the current playing video and one for the new one, one the loaded or canplay events are fired, then swap them...